# How to use user input as comparison operator?

Tags: python

What is the best way to achieve this:

```
user_input = ">"

if 2 user_input 3:
    print("yes")
```

I want to avoid writing another `if` statement:

```
if user_input == ">":
    if 2 > 3:
        print("yes")
```

Comment: use `and` operator !!  `if user_input == ">" and 2 > 3:`

Answer (score 7):

You can use  `operator` module:

```
from operator import gt, lt
op_dict = {">": gt, "<": lt}
user_input = input("Enter comparison operator: ")
comp = op_dict[user_input]
if comp(2, 3):
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 4):

You could map user inputs to different functions, which then you can select and apply to your numbers.

Example:

```
commands = {
  ">" : lambda x, y : x > y,
  "<" : lambda x, y : x < y,
  ">=": lambda x, y : x >= y
}

user_selection = input() # say ">" is chosen
if commands[user_selection](2, 3):
    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
if user_input == ">":
    print("yes\n"*(2 > 3), end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use eval to evaluate any expression.

As per you above code. The output can be achieved in below way.

```
user_input = ">"

if eval("2"+user_input+"3"):
    print("yes")
```

Comment: You can use `eval` but you shouldn't use `eval`. In 99,9% of all cases there is a better way. Read: [Eval really is dangerous.](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score 1):

So simple, if you wanna avoid another if statement just use `and` operator

```
user_input = ">"
n1 = 2
n2 = 3
if user_input == ">" and n1 > n2:
        print("yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `eval` function to evaluate a string as a statement:

```
user_input = ">"
n1 = 2
n2 = 3

if eval(str(n1) + user_input + str(n2)):
   print("yes")
```